# merge two domain objects and reassign children to one of them in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, merge, grails-orm

I have two entries in a domain entity that I want to merge.  Let's call the parent House and the children Room.  I have a situation where I want to merge two House domains that are actually the same.  I have the logic to do this top level merge.

However, I want to know if there is a way in Grails to easily say, 'go through the domain objects and wherever there is a fk pointer to House, update that fk to a new value'.

The code would be something like this

```
houseInst1.magicMerge(houseInst2)
```

This would run the House merge as well as check for every domain object that has a pointer (fk) to House and update where it points to houseInst2 originally to point to houseInst1.

Update:  One key feature is that I'd like this to work if someone adds another domain object with a link to the master object.  eg. if someone added Mortgages later, I don't want to update all my merge logic, it should go and find that Mortgages is a child of House, and update accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grails domain objects expose the hibernate `merge()` method, but this does something completely different: it merges a (possibly detached) object back into the persistence context.

I'm not aware of any built in functionality to merge two objects like you describe.  I think you need to manually update the foreign keys as in Gregg's answer.  A more efficient way to do the update would be through HQL like so:

```
Room.executeUpdate('update Room set house = :newHouse where house = :oldHouse',
    [newHouse: newHouse, oldHouse: oldHouse])
```

Edit: to automatically update all the associations, you can interrogate the Artefact:

```
def artefact = grailsApplication.getArtefact("Domain", "House")
artefact.associationMap.values().each { associationClass ->
    associationClass.executeUpdate("update ${associationClass.simpleName} set house = :newHouse where house = :oldHouse",
        [newHouse: newHouse, oldHouse: oldHouse])
}
```

Comment: I made one update, I realize how to do this if I know the relationships.  I'd like to be able to inspect all relationships and update the all children of House.  This way there is less maintenance.

Comment: Updated my answer to dynamically grab the associations and update `house` on all of them.

Comment: awesome, I think this is exactly what I'm looking for.  Doe the associationMap work even if House doesn't have a hasMany defined?

Comment: A quick test shows associations will only show up in the associationMap if there is a `hasMany` relationship defined.  If you _really_ need to find all associations, including those that don't have a declared relationship, you can get all the domain class artefacts with `grailsApplication.getArtefacts("Domain")` and check them individually for properties of type `House`.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?  You'll want to do this before you get rid of the old house.

```
Room.findAllByHouse(oldHouse).each { room ->
    room.house = newHouse
    room.save()
}
```

I haven't tried this and I'm assuming a pretty standard OneToMany relationship between House and Room.